# Manually Run Rosetta 2 on x86 Binary

Tags: rosetta, universal-binaries, apple-silicon

I wrote a very simple C program and my goal is to build an x86-only binary and then run that binary on an Apple Silicon Mac and have Rosetta 2 translate it into a Universal 2 binary. I want to look at the Rosetta 2-translated binary specifically; I'm **not** looking to build a Universal 2 app myself (that would be trivial).

I attempted to run the program through Terminal (`$ ./helloworld`) and even stick it inside of a `.app`, put it in the Applications folder, and double-click it. In both cases, the program runs correctly, but according to `$ file helloworld`, the binary is still x86-only (Rosetta 2 didn't add an arm64 executable).

Any idea how to force Rosetta 2 to translate a binary?

Comment: Are you looking for Rosetta to create an arm64 executable from the x86 binary?

Why not just build the app as a arm64 to begin with?

Comment: @ErniePC12 Yes. I want to disassemble the translated arm64 binary and compare it to a natively-built binary.

Comment: To force the app to open under Rosetta, check the box in the Get Info window. But I'm not sure that it would modify the app with the translated binary.  It would probably place that translated binary somewhere in a sandbox.  Maybe check /Library/Application Support/?

Comment: Rosetta doesn't work like this—it's an *emulator* which translates instructions at runtime. While some instructions do get translated before first run, Rosetta cannot and does not do this for the entire executable. (Well, maybe it theoretically _could_ for a very simple program, but it's not designed to work that way, because it can't in the general case.)

Comment: Wowfunhappy: completely wrong. Rosetta2 _is_ a translator.

Comment: Well, perhaps I should have said more clearly that it's a hybrid—it translates some sections but emulates others. You can't fully translate a binary ahead of time, because the binary can rewrite its own code. Rosetta's "translation" is not self-sufficient in the way the OP is imagining.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I'm aware that some binaries can't be fully translated ahead-of-time (e.g. JIT code), but Rosetta 2 does do _some_ translation at install-time. In the case of my hello world program, it should be able to translate everything, but even if not, it must translate _something_. My goal is to figure out how to trigger this translation and where the translated binary ends up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit late, but you can directly run `oahd-helper` and pass it two file descriptors (the x86 binary to translate as the first and a file to output the translated bin to as the second). The location of `oahd-helper` varies (on Big Sur it’s in /Library/Apple/usr/libexec/oah, on Monterey its /usr/libexec/rosetta). I made a gist that makes the process simpler, you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/sunflsks/00fe7c740f3b1d9668f55dff80707d03

Comment: Thank you! Your bash script worked for me.

Comment: Is this capable of working on individual object files, or full binaries only? Is there anything capable of doing it at an object file level?

Comment: @MalcolmMacLeod did you ever discover if this could convert objects?

Comment: @David Unfortunately not, temporarily put the task I had in mind for this on hold for more important things... Still something I need to look at in the near future so very interested in the answer. Will update here when/if I try if nobody else gets there first.

Comment: How can I do this for non-executable binaries, such as bundle, plugin, or library?

Answer (score 0):

If you've written a program in C, simply compile the program twice, using Mac's version of `gcc`, and then use `lipo` to combine them into one program.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building_a_universal_macos_binary for Apple's explanation of the process to create a universal Binary (containing both x86_64 and ARM64)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My goal is to disassemble the Rosetta 2-translated binary and compare it to a natively-compiled binary (to get an idea of how Rosetta 2 works). I updated my question to make this clear. Also, to add on to your answer, if the goal is to make a Universal 2 binary (which it isn't in my case), you can just use Xcode and set the build device to "Any Mac (Apple Silicon, Intel)".