# How does Rosetta 2 work?

Tags: rosetta, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I'd love to understand more about how Rosetta 2 works. The [Apple Developer article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/about_the_rosetta_translation_environment) is brief. Has anyone done a deep analysis on how Rosetta 2 works, how it is invoked and whether it's possible to use it via an API?

Some questions:

- How are x86_64 applications launched under Rosetta?
- Is it possible to dynamically invoke translation for a portion of x86 instructions?
- Might it be possible to bridge Rosetta to QEMU or similar to allow fast virtualization of Intel Docker images?

Comment: We strongly encourage one question per question. Even when related, it works far better to ask each clearly and then follow up with one question that combines one or two items to synthesize an answer that depends on a couple items.

Comment: Question 2 needs to stand alone “ Is it possible to dynamically invoke translation for a portion of x86 instructions?” it’s an excellent question and should be asked and answered here in some detail past a “yes/no” summary answer.

Comment: Same with docker and qemu questions so those two questions would be idea, to ask now as both are running on M1 now. I absolutely encourage these questions in proper sized chunks.

Comment: I suppose at the moment there’s so little information on this subject on Google or elsewhere that *any links* to relevant information are useful. 
Agree separate questions would be better once anyone has managed to delve into the black box which is Rosetta-2.

Answer (score 18):

Rosetta 2 works by doing an ahead-of-time (AOT) translation of the Intel code to corresponding ARM code. It is able to do this efficiently and easily mainly because the M1 CPU contains a special instruction that switches the memory-ordering model observed by the CPU for that thread into a model equivalent to the Intel x86 model (TSO - total store order). This has to do with how programs can expect memory consistency to work when having multiple processors (i.e. cores in this case).

User's can observe the translation the first time they launch an Intel app on the M1 as the first launch is slow. The translated code is cached and used on subsequent, much faster launches.

If you have a binary that is valid for several different architectures, you can specifically invoke Rosetta 2 by specifying that you want to launch the Intel code. You can do that from the terminal like this:

```
arch -x86_64 ./mycommand
```

Note that this setting also applies to any program that the "mycommand" process should choose to run.

Rosetta 2 as delivered by Apple in macOS Big Sur is not setup to dynamically invoke translation for a portion of x86 instructions. It is entirely focused on doing an AOT translation of the whole binary in advance. There's no user interface for translating a few small set of instructions on the fly. Rosetta 2 does include a JIT engine that allows translating instructions on the fly (for example if you run an Intel-based browser with a JIT JavaScript engine) - it is however not a general purpose JIT-engine that you could use for other purposes through an API or similar.

If you want to do that for research purposes or just out of "pure interest", then you could just take the instructions you want to translate and add them to a simple application shell (essentially adding them to a simple main()-only C program for example) and run it. The cached, translated version of the program then includes the translated instructions for inspection.

The cache is available in these folders:

```
/var/db/oah/
/System/Library/dyld/aot_shared_cache
```

There's no immediate way of "bridging" Rosetta 2 to QEMU to allow fast virtualization of Intel Docker images. QEMU contains its own Intel x86 emulation, so you could get it to run Intel Docker images on the M1 without involving Rosetta 2 at all. In this case, "fast" is a very subjective measure.

Comment: `aot_shared_cache` is a (big) file, are there any tools available to extract specific content?

Comment: I don't think Apple supplies any tools specifically for working with the aot_shared_cache file, including ones that would allow you to search for and extract specific content. For now you'll have to make do with a hexeditor or similar tools.

Comment: This probably makes it unusable for practical purposes, at least until somebody reverse-engineers the file format. The file is over one GB, at least here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. FWIW the 'AOT' claim is at least disputed - instead Hector Martin calls it a JIT + a code-cache:
https://twitter.com/marcan42/status/1328956667548082177?s=20

Comment: @JamesBlackburn It's not really disputed - it's just people splitting hairs. These terms do not have the strict definitions which that tweet assumes. If you translate from one set of machine code (be it a virtual machine or actual physical machine) to another set of machine code, and you do it before you run the program - then that's ahead-of-time. This is what Apple essentially do with Rosetta 2. If you want to be able to run the vast majority of Intel apps, you also need to do JIT (just-in-time) compilation as you'll find lots of programs doing code-manipulation on the fly.

Comment: @nohillside I wouldn't say that it is unusable. For research purposes it is not that difficult. You can start off with a clean cache, save a copy, then run your Intel program, and then diff the two cache files. You'll find the new cached entry quite easily that way.

Comment: I do think marcan has the right of it. As he points out, if Rosetta isn't an emulator, neither are a lot of things we think of as emulators, like Dolphin. And Apple's description leads to misguided questions, like "where can I find the M1 binary that Rosetta created": https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406787/manually-run-rosetta-2-on-x86-binary (The answer is, you can't, there's a cache but Rosetta still needs to do lots of work at runtime.)

Comment: No, not really. Now you’re introducing the term emulator to the discussion - I didn’t say anything about emulators before. It is really a pointless discussion as one is not arguing substance, but rather that some wants to have very strict definitions of these terms - strict definitions which are not universally agreed upon in the scientific community. You can view any JIT compiler as an emulator, and therefore as Rosetta 2 includes a JIT component, it is therefore also an emulator. But it is really pointless as it doesn’t add or subtract anything from what Rosetta 2 is. It still has AOT

Comment: translation. Whether the result of that is placed in single file per binary besides the original binary, or in one gigantic cache file in a separate location is really irrelevant. I don’t see why you think that Rosetta 2 needs to do “a lot of work” at runtime - it only needs to do that in cases that cannot be translated ahead of time. I.e. self modifying code and the like.

Comment: @jksoegaard Do you have an officiale reference for the claim about M1 cores natively supporting enabling TSO?

Comment: I do not have public Apple documentation that I can link to, I'm afraid. However, it is not really a secret, as the information has been public knowledge for some time. You can actually try it out in practice on your own M1 computer (if you have one). Note that the feature is only available on the performance cores in the M1, not the energy-efficient cores. An easy way to test is to manipulate the struct thread for your thread to set a flag to indicate you want TSO behavior. You can download source code for that here: https://github.com/saagarjha/TSOEnabler

Answer (score 7):

This is an answer for a deep analysis on how Rosetta 2 works.

I have reverse-engineered Rosetta 2 a little bit. For more details, see the GitHub pages of [this project](https://github.com/FFRI/ProjectChampollion).

Cache files of Rosetta 2 are located at both `/System/Library/dyld/aot_shared_cache` and `/var/db/oah/`.

`/System/Library/dyld/aot_shared_cache` contains only translated results for System dylibs (e.g., `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib`, `/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib` You can see the full list [here](https://github.com/FFRI/ProjectChampollion/blob/main/AotSharedCacheExtractor/aot_mapped_module_names) for macOS Big Sur version 11.1). This file contains multiple cache files for System dylibs, so its file size is huge.

For non-system binaries such as third-party x86_64 binaries, the files with aot extension under `/var/db/oah` contain the translated results.

> aot_shared_cache is a (big) file, are there any tools available to extract specific content?

@nohillside I have created [a simple python script](https://github.com/FFRI/ProjectChampollion/blob/main/AotSharedCacheExtractor/main.py) to show the contents of `aot_shared_cache`. You can use this script to extract specific content.

Comment: Great work! Can't wait for the next "chapters"!

Comment: `sudo ls -l /var/db/oah` -> `ls: oah: Operation not permitted` :-\

Comment: You need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) to access /var/db/oah because files under /var/db/oah is protected by SIP by default.